# Two different update statements - Only one working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two different variations of update statements for a stored procedure. The top one does not work and the bottom one does.

Could any of you please provide insight as to why it doesn't?

```
UPDATE table1
SET outcome = (
    SELECT outcome
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.StatusID = table2.StatusID
    AND table1.IDUser = table2.UserID
)
```

The one below works, even though I have exactly the same constraints.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.outcome = b.outcome
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B ON A.IDUser = B.UserID AND A.StatusID = B.StatusID
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? No updates, wrong updates, error etc?

Comment: Update doesn't return the results; keeps the outcome as NULL. However, the second one does.

Comment: There's no `SELECT` in your second statement - could that be the issue?

Comment: The second statement works, it's the first one that doesn't.

Comment: Try `SELECT table2.outcome` in the first example.

Comment: It would help if you specify which error is returned, I am guessing this is the error: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Check the output of this query: SELECT outcome
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.StatusID = table2.StatusID
    AND table1.IDUser = table2.UserID

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam I can see the correct results when doing this.

Comment: You have to change outer query as select outcom from(....)

Comment: Add sample tableA and tableB data (before UPDATE), and expected tableA data after UPDATE.

Answer (score 3):

The first update will fail, when there are more rows in *table2* matching the join. The second update will pick an arbitrary value for *outcome* from the join and use that value in the update.

This change to the first update should work, or rather give the same result:

```
UPDATE table1
SET outcome = (
    SELECT TOP 1 outcome
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.StatusID = table2.StatusID
    AND table1.IDUser = table2.UserID
)
```

Maybe this would be better than your existing update. This way you will have some control of which value will end up in *outcome* in *table1*:

```
UPDATE table1
SET outcome = (
    SELECT MAX(outcome)
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.StatusID = table2.StatusID
    AND table1.IDUser = table2.UserID
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that first query does not work the way you want because it is a wrong query.

Your first code has a main query and a sub query.
In your subquery, you join the tables and get a result set.
But in your main query, you set your every row with the returned result from sub query, since you have no where block. There should be a null value in that result set. This is the reason of you having null after update.

You must do the joining out of your subquery, exactly like you do in the second code.

Comment: Well spotted, that is the issue, when there are no matches between the tables, table1 will be updated to null

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table1
SET outcome = (
    SELECT TOP(1)outcome
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.StatusID = table1.StatusID
    AND table2.IDUser = table1.IDUser
)
```

Comment: I am not using parameters.